# Has Apple finally included APFS support for traditional hard drives in the latest update for macOS 10.13.1?

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, ssd, apfs

macOS High Sierra comes with a new file system APFS, now according to official notes APFS for now only supports modern SSDs.

My Mac runs on a traditional rotational hard drive and according to Apple macOS High Sierra 10.13.0. Apple recently released 10.13.1 and after updating to the latest version I booted into the recovery and after opening disk utility and going through the menu bar options I came across option know as convert to APFS, so my concern is that after the recent update has Apple finally included APFS support for traditional hard drives and should I convert my drive to the latest APFS filesystem

Comment: Do you mean 10.14, Mojave?? I wouldn't opt for APFS under High Sierra, even on an SSD. Mojave has been sound for SSDs, not tested on an HD.

Comment: @Tetsujin Nope, I don't want to upgrade to Mojave yet.

Comment: Then I really would leave APFS alone; it was bad on High Sierra. You should at least be on 10.13.6 even if you don't want Mojave yet [which is far better than either of the Sierras anyway]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to official documents and several online forums it has been confirmed that Apple is converting each and every internal HDDs into APFS File System, only when you upgrade to **macOS Mojave.**

APFS File System doesn't seems to create much problems in old macOS Devices with an internal HDD. So you should upgrade to the latest macOS version available i.e. macOS Mojave.

Comment: I have upgraded to Mojave and everything seems to work fine

Answer (score 1):

I have been using APFS on an external HDD for both High Sierra and Mojave for quite a while now. However, I have never converted a filesystem with macOS installed to APFS. In other words, I have always formatted a partition to APFS before installing macOS. Although, I do not foresee any problems with converting to APFS after macOS is installed.

You do not mention in your question if you are using Core Storage, encryption or a Fusion drive.

Do do not think there ever was a requirement that APFS was restricted to SSD. I believe High Sierra did not support APFS on Fusion drives.

Comment: I took the risk and upgraded to Mojave and surprisingly the installer converted my core storage to an APFS Volume